# NetBeans "folder doesn't contain JDK" installation problem

Tags: java, netbeans

When trying to install NetBeans, this message pops up blocking me from proceeding the installation process:

[image]

Comment: I used NetBeans 8 until just recent, this should work.  Are you **sure** that you have browsed to the correct directory?  You haven't removed any files from that JDK directory or tried to delete the entire thing?

Comment: Have you tried using a newer version of NetBeans? [The download page of 8.2](https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.2/) mentions "_Using JDK 9 or later with NetBeans IDE? [Use Apache NetBeans.](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html)_".

Comment: Actually, a newer version of NetBeans might be a good idea.  I seem to recall that the faster release schedule meant changes to the JDK's file structure.  Either that, or get an older (JDK 8?) version of the JDK and try that.

Comment: make sure that the target JDK folder contains indeed a valid JDK installation

Comment: What is the "question", BTW?

Comment: You must not specify a JDK > 8 when using NetBeans 8.x. It is not supported, and it just won't work. If you want to use JDK 11 then [download and unzip Apache NetBeans 10.0](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the bin folder inside that one.

Comment: Selecting the `bin` folder would be incorrect. You must specify the top level directory of the JDK installation.